# java.io.BufferedWriter throttles or completely stopped during the process of writing, anyone know why?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, io

As described in the question, I have encountered a weird throttling of write speed (even paused entirely) when using `java.io.BufferedWriter` to write.

My program is trying to read from a bunch of .csv files, and repack them to another bunch of .csv files grouped by the first column.

For example, if I have a line in the .csv file `Tom, 86, 87, 88`, this line will be written to the .csv file named `Tom.csv`.

I uses a `HashMap<String, BufferedWriter>` to cache the writers so that the program only have to open / close the writers once.

(I purposely split the file listing and the process logic for debugging)

The code:

```
package dev.repackcsv;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    private static final Path USER_DIR;
    private static final Path PROP_FILE;
    private static final Properties PROPERTIES;

    private static final Path SCAN_DIR;
    private static final Path OUTPUT_DIR;

    private static final List<Path> SCANNED_FILE_LIST;
    private static final Map<String, BufferedWriter> OUTPUT_FILE_MAP;

    private static void loadProperties() {
        try (InputStream propFileInputStream = Files.newInputStream(PROP_FILE)) {
            PROPERTIES.load(propFileInputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("[Error] Failed to load properties from \"application.properties\"");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private static String getProperty(String propertyName) {
        String property = PROPERTIES.getProperty(propertyName);
        if (property == null) {
            System.err.println("[Error] Undefined property: " + propertyName);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return property;
    }

    static {
        USER_DIR = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        PROP_FILE = USER_DIR.resolve("application.properties");
        if (!Files.exists(PROP_FILE)) {
            System.err.println("[Error] \"application.properties\" file does not exist.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        PROPERTIES = new Properties();
        loadProperties();
        SCAN_DIR = Paths.get(getProperty("scan.dir")).toAbsolutePath();
        if (!Files.exists(SCAN_DIR)) {
            System.err.println("[Error] Scan directory does not exist");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        OUTPUT_DIR = Paths.get(getProperty("output.dir")).toAbsolutePath();
        if (!Files.exists(OUTPUT_DIR)) {
            System.err.println("[Error] Output directory does not exist");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        SCANNED_FILE_LIST = new LinkedList<>();
        OUTPUT_FILE_MAP = new HashMap<>();
    }

    private static void loadScannedFileList()
            throws IOException {
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(SCAN_DIR)) {
            for (Path path : ds) {
                SCANNED_FILE_LIST.add(path.toAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }

    private static BufferedWriter getOutputFileBufferedWriter(String key, String headLine) throws IOException {
        if (OUTPUT_FILE_MAP.containsKey(key)) {
            return OUTPUT_FILE_MAP.get(key);
        } else {
            Path outputFile = OUTPUT_DIR.resolve(key + ".csv");
            boolean isNewFile = false;
            if (!Files.exists(outputFile)) {
                Files.createFile(outputFile);
                isNewFile = true;
            }
            BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFile);
            if (isNewFile) {
                bw.write(headLine);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
            }
            OUTPUT_FILE_MAP.put(key, bw);
            return bw;
        }
    }

    private static void processScannedCSV(Path csvFile)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.printf("[Info] Current file \"%s\"%n", csvFile);
        long fileSize = Files.size(csvFile);
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Files.newInputStream(csvFile)))) {
            String headLine = br.readLine();
            if (headLine == null) { return; }
            String dataLine;
            long readByteSize = 0;
            while ((dataLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                int firstCommaIndex = dataLine.indexOf(',');
                if (firstCommaIndex == -1) { continue; }
                BufferedWriter bw = getOutputFileBufferedWriter(dataLine.substring(0, firstCommaIndex), headLine);
                bw.write(dataLine);
                bw.newLine();
                readByteSize += dataLine.getBytes().length;
                System.out.print("\r[Progress] " + readByteSize + '/' + fileSize);
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\r");
    }

    private static void processScannedFiles()
            throws IOException {
        for (Path file : SCANNED_FILE_LIST) {
            if (!Files.exists(file)) {
                System.out.printf("[WARN] Scanned file \"%s\" does not exist, skipping...%n", file);
                continue;
            }
            if (!file.toString().endsWith(".csv")) { continue; }
            processScannedCSV(file);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException {
        loadScannedFileList();
        processScannedFiles();
        for (BufferedWriter bw : OUTPUT_FILE_MAP.values()) {
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
        }
    }

}
```

The output (For this scenario the program is freezed during the line `bw.write(dataLine);`):

- I uses Intellij-IDEA as the editor and executes the program using debug mode.

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:25111', transport: 'socket'
[Info] Current file "..\scan-dir\L2_options_20150102.csv"
[Progress] 8166463/109787564
```

It would be great if anyone knows the cause / has a solution for this :(
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having many files open can be a heavy load on the disk operating system, the number of file handles (limited!), and "moving the write head around" should one do things concurrently.

***About the `static`s***

The code shows experience (also concerning Java), maybe also from a language like C. Because the use of `static` is unusual. you could in `main` do a `new Main().executeMyThings();` and drop `static` elsewhere.

***Measures to take***

- Do not use *text* but *binary data*, `not` Writer/Reader, but `OutputStream/InputStream`. This prevent a Unicode conversion back and forth. Also you risk data loss, when a Windows UTF-8 file on Linux.
- Use `ArrayList` rather `LinkedList` as for many items it is likely to behave better.
- You might want to **collect file paths instead of BufferedWriters**. Every BufferedWriter is not only a OS resource, but maintains a buffer (memory). It might even be more performant, writing the head line, closing and reopening it in append mode. The headline could be written be with `Files.writeString`.
- System.out is costly. A ConsoleLogger might be safer would be safer with concurrency,
  but costs too.
- readByteSize misses the line break, 2 for Windows files.
- A BufferedWriter can be created with a larger/smaller buffer size.

  ```
        for (Path path : ds) {
            SCANNED_FILE_LIST.add(path.toAbsolutePath());
        }
  ```

might be better as:

```
        ds.forEach(path -> SCANNED_FILE_LIST.add(path.toAbsolutePath());
```